# Why my listview Delete always last view from list

Tags: java, android, listview

I am adding Values to array and adapter and when i delete the specific item form listview it delete from arraylist perfectly but its delete the last view its mean if i have

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

when i delete b ....the e view is gones why...then the list is

```
a
b
c
d
```

I worked on this from last 2 week but i cannot find the error in this help me.
Please
Please
Please
Please

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button addMoreBtn,checkoutBtn;
    MedicineBean medicineBean;
    //CustomAdapter customAdapter;
    ArrayList<MedicineBean> medOrderList;
    //<MedicineBean> medOrderList1;
    MyDBHandler db;
    ListView listView;
    int cust_id;
    EditText med_nameET, med_potencyET, med_qtyET;
    ImageButton increaseQty,decreaseQty;
    HomeListViewHandler homeListViewHandler;
    private ArrayAdapter<MedicineBean> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        String session_exp = SessionUtil.getSessionExpire(Home.this);
        if(Constants.LOGGING)
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Session Exp = "+session_exp+" Today Date "+new DateAndTimeUtil().getCurrentDate(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //30 days session expire checker
        if(session_exp.matches(new DateAndTimeUtil().getCurrentDate())){
            SessionUtil.setSignout(Home.this);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Session has been expired due to 30 days limit exceeded",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this, SignIn.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        //first check, Is user LOGGED IN  or not
        else if(SessionUtil.isLoggedIn(Home.this)) {

            Toolbar toolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.easymed_toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolBar);
            toolBar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.home));
            DrawerUtil.getDrawer(this, toolBar);

            addMoreBtn      = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addtoList);
            checkoutBtn     = (Button) findViewById(R.id.checkOutBtn);
            listView        = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.medListView);
            med_nameET      = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.frstSingleItemET);
            med_potencyET   = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.scndSingleItemET);
            med_qtyET       = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.thrdSingleItemTV);
            increaseQty=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.increaceImgBtn);
            decreaseQty=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.decreaseImgBtn) ;
            medOrderList    = new ArrayList<MedicineBean>();
            //medOrderList1    = new ArrayList<MedicineBean>();
            cust_id         = SessionUtil.getCustomerId(Home.this);
            medicineBean    = new MedicineBean();
            db              = new MyDBHandler(Home.this);
            //customAdapter   = new CustomAdapter();
            adapter=new CustomAdapter(this,0,medOrderList);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);


            increaseQty.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if(Constants.LOGGING)
                        System.out.println("Increment Btn pressed");
                    int val = Integer.parseInt(med_qtyET  .getText().toString());
                    val=val+1;
                    String str = Integer.toString(val);
                    med_qtyET  .setText(str);

                }
            });

           decreaseQty.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    int val = Integer.parseInt(med_qtyET  .getText().toString());
                    if(val>0) {
                        val = val-1;
                        String str = Integer.toString(val);
                        med_qtyET.setText(str);
                    }

                }
            });
            checkoutBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //add new medicines in local DB
                    int count = 0;

                    for (int i = 0; i < medOrderList.size(); i++) {

                        String name             = medOrderList.get(i).getMediceneName();
                        String potency=medOrderList.get(i).getMedicenePotency();
                        String qty = medOrderList.get(i).getMediceneQty();

                        if (!name.matches("") && !potency.matches("") && !qty.matches("")) {

                            //Check if medicine with same potency available in DB then quantity of medicine add
                            Cursor cursor = db.getMedByNameAndPotency(cust_id,name,potency);
                            if(cursor.getCount()>0)
                            {
                                cursor.moveToNext();
                                String qtyInDB      = cursor.getString(0);
                                int qtyInDBInt      = Integer.parseInt(qtyInDB);
                                int getQtyFromET    = Integer.parseInt(qtyInDB);
                                int resultOfSumQty  = getQtyFromET  +   qtyInDBInt;
                                db.updateMedQTY(cust_id,name,potency,resultOfSumQty);
                            }
                            //add new medicine
                            else if (db.addUsersMed(cust_id, name, potency, qty) != -1) {
                                medicineBean.setCust_id(cust_id);
                                medicineBean.setMediceneName(name);
                                medicineBean.setMedicenePotency(potency);
                                medicineBean.setMediceneQty(qty);
                                medOrderList.set(i, medicineBean);
                                //Log.i(Constants.TAG,medOrderList.get(i).toString());
                                count++;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    if (count > 0) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Medicines added successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Medicines not added into cart.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this, Cart.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });

            addMoreBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {


                    if (!med_nameET.getText().toString().matches("") && !med_potencyET.getText().toString().matches("")
                            && !med_qtyET.getText().toString().matches("0")) {

                        medOrderList.add(new MedicineBean(cust_id,med_nameET.getText().toString(),med_potencyET.getText().toString(),med_qtyET.getText().toString()));
                        med_nameET.setText("");
                        med_potencyET.setText("");
                        med_qtyET.setText("0");
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        Log.d("data",String.valueOf(medOrderList.size()));

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please fill all empty fields then press \'Add More\' button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            });

        }
        else
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this, SignIn.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }



    }












    private class ListViewHolder{

        EditText medET;
        EditText potencyET;
        EditText incrOrDecET;
        ImageButton cancelBtn;


    }

    class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MedicineBean> {
        private Context context;
        private List<MedicineBean> medicineBeanList;
        ListViewHolder listViewHolder;

        public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<MedicineBean> objects) {

            super(context, resource, objects);
            this.context = context;
            this.medicineBeanList = objects;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return medicineBeanList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public MedicineBean getItem(int i) {
            return medicineBeanList.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return i;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {


            if(view==null) {
                view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.single_item, null);
                listViewHolder = new ListViewHolder();
                listViewHolder.medET = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.mediceNameInHomeList);
                listViewHolder.potencyET = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.medicePotencyInHomeList);
                listViewHolder.incrOrDecET = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.mediceQtyInHomeList);
                listViewHolder.cancelBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.homeCnclBtn);
                listViewHolder.medET.setEnabled(false);
                listViewHolder.potencyET.setEnabled(false);
                listViewHolder.incrOrDecET.setEnabled(false);
                view.setTag(listViewHolder);


                listViewHolder.medET.setText(medicineBeanList.get(i).getMediceneName());
                listViewHolder.potencyET.setText(medicineBeanList.get(i).getMedicenePotency());
                listViewHolder.incrOrDecET.setText(medicineBeanList.get(i).getMediceneQty());

                listViewHolder.cancelBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        try {


                            adapter.remove(medicineBeanList.get(i));
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            /*for (int pos = 0; pos < medOrderList.size(); pos++)
                            {

                                listViewHolder.medET.setText(medOrderList.get(pos).getMediceneName());
                                listViewHolder.potencyET.setText(medOrderList.get(pos).getMedicenePotency());
                                listViewHolder.incrOrDecET.setText(medOrderList.get(pos).getMediceneQty());
                                //adapter.add(new MedicineBean(medOrderList.get(pos).getCust_id(),medOrderList.get(pos).getMediceneName(),medOrderList.get(pos).getMedicenePotency(),medOrderList.get(pos).getMediceneQty()));
                            }*/

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }
                });
            }

            return view;
        }

    }



}
```

Comment: because of position issue use **SetTag** and **GetTag** while removing on button click

Comment: Arbaz.in please explain little more in detail

Comment: read the answer

Comment: if you do not have problem why not moving to recylerview. it will make your life easy as it has own removeItem(position) from adapter and delete data from array as you are doing. if you want i can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**just Replace your adapter code with below code** and read comment which i have mention in this code

```
 class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MedicineBean> {
    private Context context;
    private List<MedicineBean> medicineBeanList;
    ListViewHolder listViewHolder;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<MedicineBean> objects) {

        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.medicineBeanList = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return medicineBeanList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public MedicineBean getItem(int i) {
        return medicineBeanList.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {


        if(view==null) {
            view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.single_item, null);
            listViewHolder = new ListViewHolder();
            listViewHolder.medET = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.mediceNameInHomeList);
            listViewHolder.potencyET = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.medicePotencyInHomeList);
            listViewHolder.incrOrDecET = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.mediceQtyInHomeList);
            listViewHolder.cancelBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.homeCnclBtn);
            listViewHolder.medET.setEnabled(false);
            listViewHolder.potencyET.setEnabled(false);
            listViewHolder.incrOrDecET.setEnabled(false);
            view.setTag(listViewHolder);
            //Add this line 
            listViewHolder.cancelBtn.setTag(i);

            listViewHolder.medET.setText(medicineBeanList.get(i).getMediceneName());
            listViewHolder.potencyET.setText(medicineBeanList.get(i).getMedicenePotency());
            listViewHolder.incrOrDecET.setText(medicineBeanList.get(i).getMediceneQty());

            listViewHolder.cancelBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    try {

                            //add this line
                            int selectedPos = (int) v.getTag();
                            //Replace this 
                              //adapter.remove(medicineBeanList.get(i));
                              //with this
                       adapter.remove(medicineBeanList.get(selectedPos));

                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        /*for (int pos = 0; pos < medOrderList.size(); pos++)
                        {

                            listViewHolder.medET.setText(medOrderList.get(pos).getMediceneName());
                            listViewHolder.potencyET.setText(medOrderList.get(pos).getMedicenePotency());
                            listViewHolder.incrOrDecET.setText(medOrderList.get(pos).getMediceneQty());
                            //adapter.add(new MedicineBean(medOrderList.get(pos).getCust_id(),medOrderList.get(pos).getMediceneName(),medOrderList.get(pos).getMedicenePotency(),medOrderList.get(pos).getMediceneQty()));
                        }*/

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
            });
        }

        return view;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Its also not working ..value is deleted from array list but the last view is deleted

Comment: Arbaz.in its not working .still delete the last view of list

Comment: debug that code and check which position you get while you click on remove button

Comment: @AshuKumar ,
he was ask for help why you put comment like this
**if you want i can help you**

Answer (score 0):

Delete the value from list then refresh the adapter.

```
  listViewHolder.cancelBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    try {
                   String item = medicineBeanList.get(i);
                   medicineBeanList.remove(position);
                   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();}
                   catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: I have done this before update my code but its also delete the last item view

Comment: did you debug that after remove array size?

Comment: I didnot understand sasikumar

Comment: String item = medicineBeanList.get(i);
                       medicineBeanList.remove(item);
                       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  check this

Answer (score 0):

I cannot resolve from any thing then i decide to referesh mean when item deleted the list view with referesh mean list view invisible and then visible with set of new adapter.
Becuase when i deleted the listview item .the item is delete perfectly from the array only orblem in in views.
Thats when i referesh the listview after delete .
Like this.

```
    listView.setVisibility(ListView.VISIBLE);
    adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,0,medOrderList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: doing this will cost you for adapter everytime and CPU and graphic rendering every time you set adapter to listview. but it will help to get ride of problem you are facing